# Pandas dataframe pivoting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `pandas DataFrame`:

```
            id               quantity  cost  type
2016-06-18  1700057817       2         2383  A
2016-06-18  1700057817       1         744   B
2016-06-19  1700057817       5         934   A
```

Here, the dates are the `index`. I need the table to be pivoted like this:

```
            id          A-quantity  A-cost  B-quantity  B-cost
2016-06-18  1700057817  2           2383    1           744
2016-06-19  1700057817  5           934     NA          NA
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried many usages of `pivot`. This is as close as I've gotten:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='id', columns='type')

            quantity   cost               
type         A    B     A     B  
id                              
1700057817   2    1     2383  744
```

Problems with this:

1. `date` index is gone
2. I needed a row per `date`-`id` combination

I've also gone through several articles on SO and elsewhere, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146338/pandas-dataframe-pivot-using-dates-and-counts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `set_index` with `append=True` followed by `unstack` and keep the `MultiIndex`:

```
df.set_index(['id', 'type'], append=True).unstack()
```

[image]

Or forcibly reformat to what you asked for:

```
# step-one same as above
df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'type'], append=True).unstack()
# collapse MultiIndex columns into '-' separated string
df1.columns = df1.columns.swaplevel(0, 1).to_series().str.join('-')
# move 'Id' from the index back into dataframe proper
df1 = df1.reset_index(1)
df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to preserve dates.

```
df.index.name = 'date'
df = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['date', 'id'], columns=['type'])
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['-'.join(tup[::-1]) for tup in df.columns]
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug, but pivot_table seems to throw away non-numeric columns. So if you add a column 'customer' of strings, this will discard it.

Comment: Oh, because pivot_table tries to aggregate, even if your values are length 1. So `pivot_table(index, columns, aggfunc = lambda x: x.values[0])` will get the strings.